# Is accepting an answer without upvoting some kind of signal to the responder?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, accepted-answer, upvotes

I'm getting a bit puzzled by this quite common practice on SO: to accept answers without giving them an upvote.

I have seen it quite a few times while reading and reviewing and experienced it first hand with some of my answers.

Is this a subtle signal of some kind whose meaning has passed me? To me it seems like a quite unpolite behaviour.

Comment: All [4 accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1743457+is%3Aa+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A0) (excluding your self-answer) are on questions by users that *cannot yet vote*.

Comment: Note that there are badges to be earned here; answering questions in low-frequency tags with a lot of new users and few votes is encouraged by awarding badges if you a) have a lot of 0-score accepted answers and b) they make up a large portion of all your accepted answers. See the [Tenacious](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) badges. One more such accepted answer and you'd be eligible, but take into account the answer must be older than 10 days before it is counted (to make sure it stayed at score 0).

Comment: Why is it impolite?  It's possible that users of this site aren't aware that you can do one without the other. It's not obvious. Why would you want to provide the option for people to accept an answer without also saying "this is useful and accurate"?

Comment: @martijnpieters, lol, we should change `unsung hero` -> `Tenacious D`

Comment: I accept without upvoting when I don't like someone's avatar. I know it's subtle, but I'm sure they'll get the hint.

Comment: What gets votes is a bit of a dark art. My 'highest' voted answers have been pretty generic, and the ones I personally feel are 'good' ... don't get much attention. *shrug*. So it goes. Not worth trying to metagame it, just concentrate on the intellectual challenge. And then rep will follow.

Comment: How is it impolite to give someone 15 points as a reward for answering the question? Being upset that someone didn't give 25 points is, to me, having a bit of the wrong priorities. The "anyone who doesn't properly reward me is rude" attitude is, at its core, selfish.

Comment: As with doing things for people in the real world, I think part of the Zen of it all is accepting that for random reasons you might be thanked heartily, halfheartedly, or not at all. Works out in the long run.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, ah, the OP didn't vote up my answer; time to change my avatar. Yeah, that makes sense :)

Comment: To me, accepting an answer is a stronger statement of its quality than upvoting it. That would make upvoting an answer I've already accepted redundant, and I think accepting should either prevent upvoting or automatically upvote. Still, I would upvote an accepted answer if I found it exceptionally useful for my case.

Comment: Some people, like myself, may not know that when you accept a helpful answer, you're "supposed" to upvote it as well. I really had no idea. Is this documented somewhere? I sincerely thought that by accepting an answer I was letting the answerer know his or her answer worked for me and I was grateful for the help. I sometimes express this in a comment as well. Now it turns out I might have been slighting him or her?

Comment: [Relavent suggestion from me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196780/possible-solution-for-accidentally-not-upvoting-accepted-answer), still can't get my head around, why such an effort gets so many negative reactions...

Comment: I do this quite often, if the answer solves the problem but the solution is un-ideal. Its still a valid answer and one which will fix the problem but that's not nessacarially the final solution for me.

Comment: I do think users who can should indeed upvote an accepted answer (except for really weird cases).

Comment: I added a related question:  Should I personally verify an answer before accepting it?   http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285883/should-i-personally-verify-an-answer-before-accepting-it

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense to accept and not upvote. Upvote means that you found the answer useful. If you accept an answer, it means it solves your problem and therefore one should presume it was also useful!

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Wouldn't it make more sense to upvote but *not* accept (yet), in that case? Not accepting any of the existing answers may spur someone else to come up with a better answer...

Answer (score 100):

We can't read the minds of people who vote or accept answers. Possibilities:

1. The answer helped the OP but the quality of the answer was just not at the level the OP finds worthy of an upvote.
2. The OP forgot to upvote.
3. The OP does not realize that upvoting and accepting are two different actions.
4. The OP does not have enough reputation to upvote. (You need 15 rep before you can upvote.)

According to Martijn Pieters' investigation, the 4th case applies to your situation. It is indeed a very common case.

Comment: 9 out of 10 times it is option 4.

Comment: For the OP it is [4 out of 4](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1743457+is%3Aa+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A0) (the fifth accepted answer is a self-answer).

Comment: That's good to know.

Comment: For me, yes. But for others? I think you might be up to something and still the answer is the same. Is there any statistics on SO of how many questions are asked by one time users and how many are asked by memebrs of the community (Rep 15 or higher).

Comment: @Einar: why does this matter? Are you trying to help people or not?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why would I not? What are you implying by that question?

Comment: @Einar: I'm implying that good answers, over time, will get upvoted. It doesn't matter if that comes from an OP (with reputation >=15) or from someone else who finds the answer in the future and found it helpful. Write answers to be helpful and the votes will come.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a fair and valid point.

Comment: I like reputation as much as the next guy but if I find a question worth answering, the OP's reputation never comes into it. I had to go look at the privileges page to find what the rep limit for upvoting was. (I incorrectly was remembering it being higher than 15 ...)

Comment: There is also a 5th possibility: the OP was not helped by the answer, and did not find it worthy of an up-vote, but wants to make sure they don't appear to be a person who receives help without ever accepting an answer, or just wants the +2 rep from accepting. I suppose they could also be playing some kind of devious prisoner's dilemma game in which they did not tit your tat.

Comment: @Mr.F Yes, it seems to happen.

Comment: @Mr.F That was far more comment when "accept rate" was a stat in the user card, but while rare, that does indeed happen.

Comment: 5. "Girl... he just in it for the SO rep..."

Comment: You forgot number 5. "User wants to keep his accepted ratio high/wants the +2 but does not care about you"

Comment: If person does not have enough reputation you can upvote the question and other questions/answers of the person. In this way account with low reputation becomes an account with a bit higher reputation which allows to upvote the answer

Answer (score 41):

In addition to the other answer, I would like to expand on point `1`: `the quality of the answer was just not at the level the OP finds worthy of an upvote`.  This is the main reason for me, although "quality" is not synonymous with "effort".

For example, the last answer that I accepted is on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830635/dyld-missing-glx-from-libx11).  The question was simple and it had a simple answer.  Was the answer helpful?  Absolutely.  Was it amazing in some way?  No.  And had the answerer added more information about linkers, for example, it would have been a waste of his time since I already know about linkers.

Contrast that with, for example, my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780145/gl-pointsize-corresponding-to-world-space-size).  This question was more complex and the answerer took the time to respond with a detailed reply.  I +1ed that button so hard--even though the answer wasn't perfectly correct.  After he fixed the math, then I accepted it.

---

As an aside, accepting an answer is 1.5 upvotes by itself--which to me says `not only is this answer good, but I support it even more since it solves my problem`.  Upvoting and accepting is 2.5 upvotes, which says `this answer is amazing and I'm going to maximally support it`.

---

Just ask/answer questions nicely and don't worry too much about it.  I get the occasional downvote for correct answers or on well-posed questions and I just let it go.  It's all imaginary internet points.

Comment: +1 for the penultimate paragraph. I think by accepting, an upvote is implied. Thats what I always felt anyway.

Comment: The "accepting is 1.5 upvotes" is true if you only look at rep. But acceptance does not count for tag badges/rankings.

Comment: Often I will accept if it solves my problem.
but not upvote and leave a comment like: "This answer is great -- it solves my problem. If you added a bit more about X, that would be awesome."

Comment: I needlessly worried that my accepting answers without upvoting was bad ettiquette.

Comment: "It's all imaginary internet points." sometimes it's hard to remember that :-)

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion, treating a lack of an upvote of your answer by the OP as "unpolite" is bizarre.  If someone upvotes your answer (whether by the question's OP or not) you should be pleased that someone found your erudition valuable.  To turn that on its head and find lack of such a vote an *insult* is, to me, really weird.  Notwithstanding the fact that *most* of those OP's *couldn't* upvote your answer, this entire attitude seems disturbingly entitled.

Bottom line -- we should treat voting as something independent.  We should not allow a vote (downvote, upvote, whatever) to bother us. We will all be much saner (and happier) with such an attitude. :)

Answer (score 13):

To my mind, the etiquette of a website is determined by the site's designers, so if they choose give one the option of accepting an answer without voting, it's acceptable.

Answer (score -7):

To me the two -- accepting and up-voting, would go together... Often a user does one without the other either out of lack of time or just not knowing how the site works.... As Jon Vinson points out above, the web-site designers could auto-tie accepting to an up-vote if they wanted to.