# Should I personally verify an answer before accepting it?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

Sometimes I have asked a question and there is quite a lag until someone answers, or I solved it myself using a work-around.  Therefore, I don't always have time to personally test or verify that the answer works.  Is it good practice to accept it anyway?

Comment: Related: [Is it reasonable to upvote an answer if you don't know if it works?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272546/3899908)

Comment: The fact that *you* no longer need that answer doesnt mean the answer is  invalid or unacceptable.  Likewise, if it results in a flicker of realization on your part why/how/when the problem was caused etc, (ie you learned something) you should consider upvoting it even if you cant/wont accept it for one reason or another.

Comment: I was caught in my early iOS days by accepting what looked like a correct answer. Months later I understood more and realised the guy was just plain wrong, but couldn't unaccept it until it was edited (IIRC). So somewhere there is an incorrect accepted answer about some basic iOS stuff...

Comment: How is that even a question? "Should I blindly click an accept button on a random answer even if I have no idea what it's doing?" If you don't know if an answer solves the problem, you're not in a position to vote on it or accept it.

Comment: The WorldBuilder beta site has a question ongoing about the best means to destroy the planet Saturn, so I wouldn't like to make this a universal rule.

Comment: Though addressing a different question, my answer at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273100/1709587 applies here almost verbatim. *"Not accepting a good answer does very little harm. Accepting a bad answer causes that answer to appear first in the list, above any better answers that people come along and post later. ... This harms everybody who ever views your question for the whole of time. ... So you should err strongly in favour of not accepting an answer at all when you [haven't tested] the answers you've received."*

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I would try to verify an answer before accepting it to avoid leading future readers astray with a poor solution to their problem.

Comment: This seems correct to me. Although I didn't personally verify it -- LOL (-:

Answer (score 26):

You wouldn't allow someone to publish code to production that they didn't have time to verify, so why would you accept someone else's solution without at least vetting it for your case?

If your workaround is sufficient for your case, there's **no harm** in posting that as an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 15):

I guess I won't be getting accepted but....

I think this generally falls under "do your best". If there are scores of answers, it is rather impractical. If you have a few, please spend the time and help future visitors.

Remember, people who look at Stackoverflow are generally trying to a) answer your question or b)find the solution to a problem. For those answering, it is more economical for the Stackoverflow community if they don't answer threads that already have a solution, but is not marked as such. Those who are looking for a solution want the answer that works, not the dozen of answers that may work. Not marking most likely decreases the efficiency of Stackoverflow for the askers and the answerers.

Comment: Good point showing the benefits to users who answer questions, not just those seeking the solution.

Answer (score 9):

I take `accepted` to mean "This one solved my problem". No more, no less. That doesn't mean it's good, comprehensive or well thought out. Merely that it gave you the specific insight you needed to solve your problem in this particular instance.

That implicitly means that you used it. If you didn't, it may well still be worthy of an upvote, but *not* an accept.

And if you did end up solving it yourself via workaround, I'd suggest it's worth adding *your specific* workaround as an answer, and 'accept' that. 
This doesn't in any way diminish other contributions made.

A "good" answer doesn't necessarily have to be the "right" answer, it just has to offer insight to people who may have similar problems. This is why we have upvotes as a separate mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If someone answers your question, but it is not the solution you used I don't believe you should accept it. While the answer may be well thought out and helpful enough to deserve an upvote, if it is not the solution you implemented than I would argue that they *did not* solve your problem.

There are often multiple ways to accomplish a task, but there can only be one accepted answer. If five people answered my question (all correctly), I would upvote all of them (assuming the answer still had good characteristics) and accept the one that I actually used.

In your case, you could certainly upvote the answer if it helps, but I would not accept it if you were unable to verify it, because if it is not a working solution it could be misleading to others. If it is a problem you solved on your own, I think it would be beneficial to post your solution when you have time, and you can always accept your answer to show readers the solution that worked best for you.

Answer (score -7):

If you've developed a workaround, post what steps you took to solve your problem, post it as an answer, and accept it.

If you notice down the road that the other answer has a ton of upvotes, feel free to mark their answer as accepted.

Comment: Why? You shouldn't be swayed by the upvotes, only by whether it worked for you.