# Accept or Accept+Upvote?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

Some of the users accept the best answer and some of them accept as well as upvote it.

Isn't accepting the answer sufficient from the OP side *(unless the answer is super cool)*?

Comment: Very related: [Is accepting an answer without upvoting some kind of signal to the responder?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285752/is-accepting-an-answer-without-upvoting-some-kind-of-signal-to-the-responder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, everybody is free to vote and accept as he/she wants (serial voting and voting fraud / sock puppets excluded).

The tooltip on the Upvote button (for answers) says

> This answer is useful

In fact, it should be *very rare* to accept an answer but not upvote it. I can think of *some* cases, e.g. where no good answer is provided, except for a workaround. But those are the minority. And of course, if the OP has less than 15 reputation, upvoting would be difficult.