# Is it correct to upvote an answer which I also accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, accepted-answer, upvotes

If a question I asks receives an answer which solved my problem, I should mark that as accepted. Should I also upvote the answer though? Will upvoting and accepting an answer give the answerer 25 reputation, and is this the right reward in this case?

What are the community ethics concerning accepting and upvoting an answer?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?r=SearchResults

Comment: `is this the right reward` I think the right number of free internet points to give someone who's helped you out is always the maximum possible :-)

Comment: "and is this the right reward in this case" - it is entirely the wrong way of thinking if you are doing this to reward people. Voting is not a reward/punishment system. We vote on quality, it is the site which is responsible for allocating and deallocating reputation points as a result of what happens. We have no choice in the matter, nor should we worry about that.

Answer (score 28):

Accepting and upvoting an answer are separate, independent actions. You are encouraged to upvote any solution which is useful<sup>1</sup>, and to accept the one which solved your problem or was most helpful in finding your solution<sup>2</sup>. This means that yes, usually you'd upvote and accept the answer which helped you most. I agree with [this answer by Glorfindel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336749/5211833) that accepting and not upvoting is an exception, unless you have [less than 15 reputation and cannot upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Since these two actions are independent, they will both give their normal reputation reward: [+10 for an upvote and +15 on an accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Thus yes, upvoting and accepting an answer will give the answerer 25 reputation.

If you think that an answer deserves even more reputation, you can [place a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the question to give more reputation.

---

<sup>1 Tooltip on the upvote button: "This answer is useful"</sup>

<sup>2 Tooltip on the accept button: "Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was most helpful in finding your solution"</sup>

Comment: _usually you'd upvote and accept the answer which helped you most._ - Then why isn't an upvote automatically triggered on answer accept, if it's something you would usually do?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton that's something you'd have to ask the SE devs. I merely interpret the tooltips. "Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was most helpful in finding your solution" and "This answer is useful" have a fairly large overlap IMO. When an answer solved your problem, it was clearly helpful for you. The former implies accepting it, the latter implies upvoting.

Comment: What about one-liners? A simple piece of code with no explanation would never receive an upvote from me, but can still be accepted when it solved the problem.

Comment: @dly So the answer solved the problem, yet you don't consider it useful...? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Gama11 Someone may interpret "this answer is useful" as "this answer is useful _to others_", then the overlap between upvote and accept decreases.

Comment: @Gama11 there'S a slight difference between helpful and well written. Upvotes are for the latter. A link to some docs or a piece of code can be helpful, but without explanation it's still a poor answer.

Comment: @dly How do you figure that upvotes are for well written answers? The tooltip literally uses the word 'helpful', not 'well written'.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton a) people can vote how they want to vote; you don't get to tell dly they're "voting wrong"; b) there's more to votes than what's in the tooltip; the tooltip is quick guidance -- a reminder of why the buttons are there, not an entire explanation of when, how, and why one should vote on the post. Also, the tooltip uses the word "useful", not "helpful" :P

Comment: @HereticMonkey a) I never told anyone they were "voting wrong". I was asking how dly came to the conclusion that they did. b) I realize this, my comment was based on the wording of the tooltip alone. And yes, it's "useful", which I had used in a previous comment, not sure how I mixed it up.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, you **must** accept answer what helped you the most. You are *free* to upvote/downvote answers, so yeah, feel free to downvote and accept. Normally doesn't happens, but is a cool feature (isn't it?) to have.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336749/5211833) given a good reason to accept and not upvote: the OP having less than 15 rep.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton that's something everyone can decide for themselves. My belief is simple: *accept = the answer helped* the OP and should be marked as such while *upvote = good quality*. Like I said before I'd never upvote a poorly written answer, even if it helped solving the problem. Votes are for curation and bad posts shouldn't be upvoted just because they're technically correct.

Comment: @Sinatr You are not required to accept an answer